# Creating a Workflow rule to populate a Custom Field with Username of person creating a new Case

Tags: workflow, case

Our account managers go into Opportunity to create a New Case. We need the simple functionality for an existing field to be populated with the username of the person creating the case.

The field that needs to be populated with the usernames name is:

Requestor | Requestor__c | Lookup(User)

So far this is the workflow and it doesn't contain a field update, because I am stuck on the field itself which is a pick list. Once again, the field would need to be updated with the Case creator:

[image]

[image]

I was thinking that maybe creating a text field instead would be a simple solution, but I need the current 'Requestor' field to stay because if we delete it, all of the previous case requesters will be gone and the org needs this information.

Please let me know if any other clarifications are needed and thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using Created By?

Comment: Currently that's what we're doing, but say that the requester changes, would there be a trigger capable of doing this or would this have to be done through apex?

Comment: Use Flow, Process, or Trigger to populate the value

Comment: @ArtemSkobrev A couple things. First, if you need to store a user, use a lookup instead of a picklist or text field. Second, Created By will never change, so if you need a requester field, it'd be independent of the creator after the initial creation, so if you still need that field, I don't think it should be automated, except perhaps on creation, and only if it's not already specified. This would allow you to, for example, allow someone to request a case on another person's behalf.